# Android textview bounds for custom font

Tags: android, fonts

Suddenly occurs problem with custom fonts.
When i apply comic font for text views,first letter is cut. I try to implement paddings and margins but unfortunately still first letter is cut. 
Images that are presented describe this problem.

I consider this [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds%20but) as well but no results.

[image: Regular font]
[image: Comic font]
This is xml textview implementation.

```
 <com.alllarm.alllarm.AutoResizeTextView
         android:id="@+id/settings_profile"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:text="@string/my_profile"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="35sp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is connected with wrong size of the textview.To solve this problem you need just adjust additional size to the textview item. Additionally this could be connected with wrong text font feature.